# Magento2 How to add column in sales order item renderer in admin order view

Tags: magento2

I have two custom fields in sales_order_item table. Now i want to show that two fields in sales order item section. I tried [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/211455/2582) solution. But it is always adding new column at the end.

So, how i can add my custom column after Item status and also should be editable? Like attached example.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your custom module, how you achieved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the solution. Using this code i am able to arrange columns as per my requirement.

```
<referenceBlock name='order_tab_info'>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items" name="order_items" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/items.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="sku" xsi:type="string" translate="true">SKU</item>
                        <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product</item>
                        <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Item Status</item>
                        <item name="product-cost" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Cost</item>
                        <item name="ship-cost" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Ship Cost</item>
                        <!-- <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Original Price</item> -->
                        <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price</item>
                        <item name="ordered-qty" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Qty</item>
                        <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Subtotal</item>
                        <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Amount</item>
                        <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tax Percent</item>
                        <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount Amount</item>
                        <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Row Total</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" as="default" name="default_order_items_renderer" template="Magento_Sales::order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="sku" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-sku</item>
                            <item name="product" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-product</item>
                            <item name="status" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-status</item>
                            <item name="product-cost" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-product-cost</item>
                            <item name="ship-cost" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-ship-cost</item>
                            <!-- <item name="price-original" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price-original</item> -->
                            <item name="price" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-price</item>
                            <item name="qty" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-ordered-qty</item>
                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-subtotal</item>
                            <item name="tax-amount" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-amount</item>
                            <item name="tax-percent" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-tax-percent</item>
                            <item name="discont" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-discont</item>
                            <item name="total" xsi:type="string" translate="false">col-total</item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Qty" name="column_qty" template="Magento_Sales::items/column/qty.phtml" group="column"/>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name" name="column_name" template="Magento_Sales::items/column/name.phtml" group="column"/>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn" name="column_sku" template="HK_CustomField::items/column/sku.phtml" group="column"/>
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn" name="column_product-cost" template="HK_CustomField::items/column/product_cost.phtml" group="column" />
                <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn" name="column_ship-cost" template="HK_CustomField::items/column/ship_cost.phtml" group="column" />
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText" name="order_item_extra_info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: This is not working for me I did the same you did. where did you define the button?